# dns server configuration for node.js

Tags: node.js, dns

I have developed server application in node.js. Right now I access the application using 128.1.1.5:3000. But i want to use a domain name like abc.net to access the application. How can I do this. Please suggest.

Comment: You want to configure the dns on local node project which is running on your local system?

Comment: @Shikhar  yes I want to configure a dns server on same machine on which my app is running. My app is on local area network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure DNS on your local app,you need to do following configuration.

1. Make an entry of this DNS example abc.net as a host instead of local host while setting up your node server where you are mentioning the localhost host and port detail eg. in app.js file.

Example

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = 'abc.net';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

2. Now open command prompt and type

`ipconfig -all`

It will list all your IPs.  Select the ip of your machine which is preferred one.mostly you can locate this ip by finding the ip which is followed by (preferred) keyword in command prompt.

3. Now copy this IP address and make an entry of this in system host file.Make sure you have an admin rights to make changes in this file.

Path of host file in Windows
**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

4. Edit this file and scroll to the end and press Enter to copy the ip address corresponding to the DNS which you have configured in node js application as shown below in new line.

   **IPaddress(fetched in step 3)
   abc.net**

**i.e ipaddress then give space then dns name**

5. Save the file.
6. Start your node application.
7. Now try hitting your api from the url **abc.net:port/api**

Comment: please clarify you first line                                                                                         "Make an entry of this DNS example abc.net as a host instead of local host while setting up your node server where you are mentioning the localhost host and port detail eg. in app.js file".  how to make this entry in app.js file

Comment: If this answer has helped you. Please considering upvoting and accepting my answer

Comment: thanks for explaining in detail. Your answer worked from my local pc but when i wanted to access it from other pc on same network then it does not work. Request you to clarify. Do i need to make any settings like dns or host file entry on that pc ?

Comment: so in that case you need to make similar entry in host file against hostname as you have done in app running pc host file.

Comment: Okk !! but in practical how it will be implemented because we cannot tell every user to make a entry into the host file. Is there an alternative like in visual studio application where we used to configure a dns server and user need to give IP address of this dns in his dns server of IP settings ??

Comment: Answers given on SO are in accordance to the question. This new question is out of the scope of this question. I have given answer in accordance to the running the node app with dns on local machine  However the resolution of your query is to get DNS registered. Please get in touch with your network team. For this where your will be deploying the application on server and your users will be using the application from here. Get this host name of server registered.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a domain that you can edit the DNS settings on and add an A record that is configured to your server's external IP address
then you can access your domain with the port attached
example: `mydomain.com:5000`

you should refer to your domain record provider's documentation on how to do this.

Beyond that, you may encounter firewall settings, port settings, and possible HTTPS certificates issues but these are separate topics each.